# Why do employers no longer invest in training employees?

Tags: communication, job-search, united-states, work-experience

As a young recent college grad looking for an entry-level positions, it's been hard finding a position that doesn't require 5+ years of experience right out of school. Even some of the entry level jobs require 3+ years of experience!

Seems to me like employers want a young worker who's in their 20s with 20+ years of experience.

What's the reason companies no longer invest in training workers?

Comment: Why haven't you applied for my job posting?  We train our people.

Comment: I've had an entry level help desk position posted for the last month and only 3 people have applied.  Combined all 3 have over 50 years experience in IT.

Comment: That's interesting as I am also in IT (hopefully lol). Crazy to me that applicants with 50 years of experience between them would  want to work in a help desk position.

Comment: @joeStrazere, sorry if I made it seem like I haven't worked in IT. I actually worked in the IT support department in the university and also volunteered at nonprofits to help with severs, networks, etc..I guess times are tough for people with that much experience to work at help desk (I'm not looking down on them) just shocked and may perhaps explain why it's difficult for me to why I can't get my foot in the door. I can't compete with 50 years!

Comment: As a note if you are a recent graduate, you need to use your Colleges placement office for assistance.  Job boards are for people that already have worked.

Comment: They do. You just need to accept that you're not going to start out doing exactly what you want.

Comment: "*Even some of the entry level jobs require 3+ years of experience!*" Those are not entry level jobs and this is not a real question but a rant.

Comment: @Lilienthal I have a sister which had a 4 years of study diploma couldn't get entry work, they wanted either the same degree with years of experience, of no experience but with lower degree that cost less. She struggle a lot and had to move at 500km+ for some 6 month replacement job to get some years of experience.

Comment: @Walfrat Perfectly possible, but entry level work has a very clear definition. You should distinguish low-level work from entry-level work, though I'll admit that a lot of people use the latter to mean the former, particularly in tough job markets. My comment was intended for the OP since a **position that outright advertises 3+ years experience is simply not entry-level**. He needs to be applying for positions with *no* experience requirements if he wants entry-level work. While it's possible that he'd compete against people who do have experience, that's very different.

Comment: @Lilienthal Well to be honest usually in IT, it isn't hard to find job just after studies (either US or Europe), so yes maybe the OP is aiming too high or in something a bit too specific for company to accept beginners.

Comment: You are probably not looking in the right places. Employers use job boards because they are looking for experienced and skilled candidates and they can't find those candidates on their own. No-skill no-experience are a dime a dozen and unfortunately for you, you are living proof of that. Many companies that actively recruit entry-level people have specific feeders set up e.g. recruiting events on college campuses. Find out who is setting up recruiting events aimed at entry-level candidates and chase these employers down. The Big Three, for example, are known to recruit on college campuses.

Comment: I don't get it, if you want an entry level job, why are you going after jobs that require 3+ years of experience? Is a person with 3+ years of experience considered an "entry level" candidate in the US? Strange! :o Here in India, we use the term "fresher" to mean an entry level candidate (a term that doesn't fly well with some of the Americans here, even though you can easily guess what it means). Perhaps Americans should also start using that term so that people are less likely to confuse 3+ years of experience with an entry level job. :P

Comment: "N years of experience" where N is low number means practically nothing.  Don't take job descriptions so literally, not everything is a "hard requirement". Also keep in mind that many/most positions are not filled by people answering postings but through personal and professional connections.

Comment: Can the reopen voter please explain why you want this question reopened?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Why do employers no longer invest in training employees?

The premise behind the question title is incorrect. Many employers do indeed invest in training employees.

What you are encountering is a market with many job seekers, but fewer positions. In that market, employers can ask for and find job seekers with experience, even for lower-level jobs. Unfortunately, you are competing against them.

Keep looking, try not to get discouraged. Many employers are willing to hire smart college graduates with minimal experience and train them up - they do indeed exist. You just may have to look harder and longer to find them.

Also consider casting your net wider. When you say "I can't compete" when you see experienced folks applying for entry-level jobs, you are probably wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Question will probably get closed as it's purely speculative and opinion. Here's mine.

1. Turnover is high these days so they view the money as a waste.
2. I've seen too many times where companies train an employee and then they leave because they weren't given a pay increase (which leads to 3)
3. Employees rarely see training as compensation in itself and feel they deserve more money which leads them to leave to go elsewhere.

The only cases I see training as an employment benefit anymore is reimbursement because it can then include a clause for repayment if they leave.

Comment: Depends on the industry. I've noticed that some of my friends in the IT field say there's a lot of turnover since promotions are hard to come by and only way they could advance was to switch jobs.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I'm referring to historically, meaning that working the majority of your career in one or two companies is the exception rather than the rule.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere in IT in France There are quite some turnover, of course it wasn't in every part of the company, pretty much where the managers were bad. Guess you aren't (/with a) bad manager. My professors said it clearly : "you will change 2/3 jobs about every two years". The idea behind this is that we will likely get stuck underpaid and in a rôle isn't that intersting neither good in the CV, unless we get lucky, but we can't get all that luck.

Comment: High turnover here except for govt jobs because they're all cowboys, just govt doesn't sack them, so eventually they all work for govt.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere exactly. My dad was a cop at the same place for 35 years, my mom was an accountant for 15 (until they closed). My grandparents both worked at the same factory for over 30. So many companies don't give decent raises as it is (they hire from outside) that it's necessary to leave to dramatically advance. Making them more qualified increases that risk.

Comment: In IT in Finland, it is more the norm than exception to see developers with 1-3 years per company than 5+ years at any one company. In Denmark, they have even turned that into a strength. People switch jobs all the time at a short notice and it is encouraged as a way to have employees find the best match for their current set of skills and interests. And in return, the companies get the best possible employees with high motivation.